# How to get a reference to angular 2 component styles list / how to load a css dynamically inside a component

Tags: angular, dynamic, sass, components

I have a component which can have 1 to many styles files depending on a dynamic variable I know after the app loads using one of my resolvers.

Is there a way to dynamically load a style file inside a component or alternatively to get a reference to the component after it was initiated and push a style file to it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can selecte which stylesheet is loaded.  But you can use the *ngIf directive to display a different style depending on the dynamic variable.

Comment: but that means I must load all the styles up front and not just the needed one, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to load styles dynamically in the styleUrls configuration of a component.

The way to override a class inside a component is either to set the viewEncapsulation to None and override the class from a global css file.

Or;

createa a selector that is stronger than the inner selector of the component.